# Can't click links because a box is covering them

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

Hello :) i got a little "slider", as shown on the screenshot. Under it, there is a link which opens the related lightbox... the problem is, the invisible box (the blue one in the screenshot) is covering the thumnails of the slider, so i cant click them. How can i fix this?

[The blue box is covering the thumbnails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oz1Ys.jpg)

The button:

```
<label class="btn" for="modal-1">more...</label>
```

Css to it:

```
.btn {
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
color: #000;
margin-top: 40vh;
margin-left: 30vw;
transform: rotate(-10deg);
z-index: 999999999;
```

Comment: try `position: relative;`

Comment: Check this it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413658/placing-callouts-over-bootstrap-carousel

Comment: What if you give it a `width` and `height` and `absolute` position ? And no need to use such big values for `z-index` ;)

Comment: i tried 'position: relative' now and it just makes the "more..." disappear. same with 'position: absolute' :/ and when i tried width and height it just made a new "blue box" to the bottom right of the text and the biiig box to the top left stayed :/

Comment: @VincentG thank you for the tip with the z-index xD the z-index of the whole lightbox was like some billions and i just decreased it and it works now :D the only problem is that the lightbox, which shows up when i hit "more..." is behind the thumbnails :D but i think i'll get this to work

Comment: @TobiasGlaus Glad to know it works now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding `position: relative;`

```
.btn {
position: relative;
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
color: #000;
margin-top: 40vh;
margin-left: 30vw;
transform: rotate(-10deg);
z-index: 999999999;
}
```